# Get Visual Studio 2010 to run a command in a prompt instead of build on F5 press?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a Visual C++ 2010 project set up but the source files use a make file to build and don't take kindly to visual C++'s compiler (some very obscure missing obj file no one has been able to help me with).

So yeah, that is my question basically, to override Visual C++'s build command to open a visual studio 2010 commandprompt and execute a command..

Comment: Like calling MsBuild from a makefile or something?

Comment: I want to run something like 'nmake' from a specific directory in a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure the project as a "makefile" project type. With a makefile project, you get to specify the commands that the IDE will execute for the build/clean/rebuild commands. As the name might suggest, it's pretty much ideal for running a makefile to perform the build.

The IDE still parses and provides intelligent code navigation for source files that are in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can try creating a pre-build event:

[image]

You can set-up a batch script there in order to copy/move externals files or any other task you need as pre-requisite for building your application.

Comment: Yeah something like that *but* without running the rest of the build process (since it creates noise and ends with an error).